# Cannot create a new react app due to errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I've been trying to learn reactjs and watched like 3-4 tutorials on how to install it on vscode.
everytime i try to run the "npx create-react-app first-program" command
it gives this  error.

I'm using nmp version - 9.6.7 and node version - 18.17.0

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\VINAYAK\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\VINAYAK\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\VINAYAK\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-23T13_38_18_684Z-debug-0.log
```

please lemme know what i have to do in order to solve it

I tried watching tutorials, asking friends but it was to no avail.
I also browsed through some question here and there but the problems weren't similar

Comment: if npm -v and node -v works. There could be an issue with the installation of a node. Have you tried reinstalling the node? Also switch to the new version of creating react app from the [new docs](https://react.dev/) `npx create-next-app` instead of `npx create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative for CRA is Vite.
You just have to use
`npm create vite@latest` and follow the instructions to create a react app.

Visit to know more https://vitejs.dev/guide/